# Conversion of JSON to Avro failed: Failed to convert JSON to Avro: Unknown union branch

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to send a JSON message to a Kafka topic using Kafka-rest service to serialize JSON as an Avro object, but the JSON message is failed to get accepted by Kafka-rest with the following error:

```
Conversion of JSON to Avro failed: Failed to convert JSON to Avro: Unknown union branch postId
```

I suspect that there is an issue with the Avro schema I am using as it is a nested record type with nullable fields.

Avro schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ExportRequest",
  "namespace": "com.example.avro.model",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "context",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": {
          "type": "string",
          "avro.java.string": "String"
        },
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "exportInfo",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "ExportInfo",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "exportId",
            "type": {
              "type": "string",
              "avro.java.string": "String"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "exportType",
            "type": {
              "type": "string",
              "avro.java.string": "String"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "exportQuery",
            "type": {
              "type": "record",
              "name": "ExportQuery",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "postExport",
                  "type": [
                    "null",
                    {
                      "type": "record",
                      "name": "PostExport",
                      "fields": [
                        {
                          "name": "postId",
                          "type": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "avro.java.string": "String"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "isCommentIncluded",
                          "type": "boolean"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "default": null
                },
                {
                  "name": "feedExport",
                  "type": [
                    "null",
                    {
                      "type": "record",
                      "name": "FeedExport",
                      "fields": [
                        {
                          "name": "accounts",
                          "type": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "avro.java.string": "String"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "recordTypes",
                          "type": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "avro.java.string": "String"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "actions",
                          "type": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "avro.java.string": "String"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "contentTypes",
                          "type": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "avro.java.string": "String"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "startDate",
                          "type": "long"
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "endDate",
                          "type": "long"
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "advancedSearch",
                          "type": [
                            "null",
                            {
                              "type": "record",
                              "name": "AdvancedSearchExport",
                              "fields": [
                                {
                                  "name": "allOfTheWords",
                                  "type": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                      "type": "string",
                                      "avro.java.string": "String"
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "name": "anyOfTheWords",
                                  "type": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                      "type": "string",
                                      "avro.java.string": "String"
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "name": "noneOfTheWords",
                                  "type": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                      "type": "string",
                                      "avro.java.string": "String"
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "name": "hashtags",
                                  "type": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                      "type": "string",
                                      "avro.java.string": "String"
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "name": "keyword",
                                  "type": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "name": "exactPhrase",
                                  "type": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          "default": null
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "default": null
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Json message:

```
   {
        "context": {
            "user_id": "1",
            "group_id": "1",
            "organization_id": "1"
        },
        "exportInfo": {
            "exportId": "93874dd7-35d7-4f1f-8cf8-051c606d920b",
            "exportType": "json",
            "exportQuery": {
                "postExport": {
                    "postId": "dd",
                    "isCommentIncluded": false
                },
                "feedExport": {
                    "accounts": [
                        "1677143852565319"
                    ],
                    "recordTypes": [],
                    "actions": [],
                    "contentTypes": [],
                    "startDate": 0,
                    "endDate": 0,
                    "advancedSearch": {
                        "allOfTheWords": [
                            "string"
                        ],
                        "anyOfTheWords": [
                            "string"
                        ],
                        "noneOfTheWords": [
                            "string"
                        ],
                        "hashtags": [
                            "string"
                        ],
                        "keyword": "string",
                        "exactPhrase": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me to understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your JSON and Avro looks good.

You are facing the issue because JSON doesn't conform to [Avro's JSON encoding spec](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.1/spec.html#json_encoding).

So, if you convert your JSON accordingly, it will somehow look like this

```
{
  "context": {
    "user_id": "1",
    "group_id": "1",
    "organization_id": "1"
  },
  "exportInfo": {
    "exportId": "93874dd7-35d7-4f1f-8cf8-051c606d920b",
    "exportType": "json",
    "exportQuery": {
      "postExport": {
        "com.example.avro.model.PostExport": {
          "postId": "dd",
          "isCommentIncluded": false
        }
      },
      "feedExport": {
        "com.example.avro.model.FeedExport": {
          "accounts": [
            "1677143852565319"
          ],
          "recordTypes": [],
          "actions": [],
          "contentTypes": [],
          "startDate": 0,
          "endDate": 0,
          "advancedSearch": {
            "com.example.avro.model.AdvancedSearchExport": {
              "allOfTheWords": [
                "string"
              ],
              "anyOfTheWords": [
                "string"
              ],
              "noneOfTheWords": [
                "string"
              ],
              "hashtags": [
                "string"
              ],
              "keyword": "string",
              "exactPhrase": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```